# Race condition in MySQL - prevent multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, innodb, race-condition

Assume I have the following situation: One user can only one active task.

So if I want to add task for a user with id 2 I need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE active=1 AND id_user = 2;
```

and if there are none records I can do

```
INSERT INTO tasks(id_user, active) VALUES(2,1);
```

The question is: if I put select and insert into transaction (and use InnoDB) can I be sure that user won't have 2 active tasks created?

The above situation is simplified but I was told that during MySQL backups (mysql inserts are queued somehow by server) user had created many active tasks that's not allowed using code like this (I don't know at the moment if transactions were used). The only working solution according to the "story" was using queues (probably Beanstalkd) to make running task after finishing another.

So the question is - is it possible that something like this could happened and if using MySQL transaction will be working solution or maybe some other solution should be used in this case?

**EDIT**

The problem here is I cannot add unique key for column, I cannot also update the record. Just to make it more accurate, the real situation is:

In table tasks there are:

id - primary key, auto incrementing
id_user - id of user
start_date 
end_date - nullable (set to null if task is not complete)

One user can only have one task that is not complete (end_date is null) so when there is at least one task with null date for a user new task for this user cannot be created. However I'm operating on old database where it's quite possible there might be many records for the same use if end_date set to null, so I cannot use here unique and each time before inserting I need to check first

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE end_date IS NOT null AND id_user = 2
```

and if there are no records then I can create new task for the user.

It's also quite possible that in future more conditions for this select will be added to verify before creating new task.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about InnoDB "transactions".  Learn about `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

But, for this situation, both can be avoided by doing:

```
UPDATE tasks SET active = 1 WHERE id_user = 2;   -- not adequate
```

Then check for the RowsAffected: 0 means it was not active.

With the **Edit**, scratch my `UPDATE`; back to a transaction.  In pseudo-code:

```
BEGIN;
$active = SELECT active FROM tasks WHERE id_user = 2 FOR UPDATE;
if ($active) exit;
INSERT INTO tasks (id_user, active, task)
    VALUES (2, 1, 'foo')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  active = 1 task = 'foo';
COMMIT;
```

This assumes you have `PRIMARY KEY(id_user)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UNIQUE` index that prevents duplicates, do this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tasks (id_user, active) VALUES (2,1)
```

That will ignore warnings about duplicate entries. This has the effect of adding the record only once.

Comment: Adding a `UNIQUE` column is the way to do this. Without that you're going to have to write some ugly, convoluted procedure and wrap it in a transaction.